# How to make a transparent circles on the background bootstrap modal window?

Tags: html, css, svg

Please tell me how is it possible to make transparent circles on the background of the modal window. I want to create this effect. When I open a modal window on a black background moving transparent circles which allow you to see the page without darkening. Effect as the light of a lantern on a black background. I created the SVG circles that move around the page, but how to do that, they did the background modal Windows are transparent and have not found. Here is a test example: [test example](http://test.azuron.ru/)
Perhaps I generally do everything wrong, please send how to do this optimally?
For such effect:
[image]

My SVG

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="550px" height="550px" viewBox="0 0 550 550" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask5">
  <circle cx="153.58" cy="250" r="100" fill="url(#grad5)">
  <animate id="c1" attributeName="cx" begin="0s;c2.end" from="0" to="250" dur="3s"></animate>
  <animate id="c2" attributeName="cx" begin="c1.end" from="250" to="0" dur="3s"></animate>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="346.42" cy="250" r="100" fill="url(#grad5)">
  <animate id="c3" attributeName="cx" begin="0s;c4.end" from="500" to="250" dur="3s"></animate>
  <animate id="c4" attributeName="cx" begin="c3.end" from="250" to="500" dur="3s"></animate>
  </circle>
  </mask>
  <radialGradient id="grad5" cx="50%" cy="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
  <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white"></stop>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://blog.studio.gd/files/admin_post/img/6.jpg?1375351354" mask="url(#mask5)" width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0"></image>
  </svg>
```

Modal Window

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          Test window
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm Sorry! It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I added a picture to make it clearer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript HTML5 Canvas drawing transparent circles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622930/javascript-html5-canvas-drawing-transparent-circles)